# Bootstrap-table override table export function

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using Bootstrap-table and I would like to export my table data to an Excel file.

I like the icons used by the bootstrap-table-export plugin and I want to use that, but I want to call my own export function for custom formatting.

In the bootstrap-table-export.js, there are a bunch of key-value pairs of strings and functions.

The one I am interested in is:

```
key: "exportTable",
      value: function exportTable(options) {
        var _this2 = this;
        ... code that does export....
```

I can alter the source to just call my code here, but I would like a way that is compatible with future versions. Can the key-value pairs be altered to override the "exportTable" function with my own code?

The documentation at https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/#exporttable gives me a clue that the exportTable function can be overridden. Is this the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it overwriting it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Overwriting the exportTable function? How? I've tried adding an exportTable parameter to the table options but that doesn't work. The only thing that I've tried that works is modifying the bootstrap-table-export.js and that works but I would prefer not to do that.